# How to keep progress indicator running in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want a progress indicator to stop only after completely updating the ui. But it stops after executing last line of code in ui method. The indicator should work as:

> ```
> 1> Start the progress
> 2> Run the progress until all nodes are added to the scene
> 3> Stop after completion
> ```

The way i update is, i pass BorderPane to the thread and set its center a gridpane, which is the last line of code after which the indicator stops.
And the loginTask, if i start it inside Application Thread the indicator does not spin !

```
borderpane.setCenter(gpane);
```

UI method

```
{
Loading loadBar = new Loading(stage);
Task<Boolean> loginTask= checkCredTask();
loginTask.setOnSucceeded(value -> {
            loadBar.hideProgress(); });

loadBar.startTask(loginTask);
(new Thread(loginTask)).start();

}
```

Progress Bar

```
public class Loading{

    private static Stage stage;
    private static ProgressIndicator p;
    private static Alert alert;

    public Loading(Stage s){
        stage=s;
        p=new ProgressIndicator();
        alert = new Alert(AlertType.NONE);

    }


    public void startTask(Task<Boolean> cm){
        if(p != null){
            p.setProgress(-1);
            p.progressProperty().unbind();
            p.progressProperty().bind(cm.progressProperty());
            alert.initOwner(stage);
            alert.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);");
            alert.getDialogPane().getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            alert.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            alert.getDialogPane().setContent(p);
            alert.show();
        }
    }


    public void hideProgress(){
        alert.setResult(ButtonType.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Task

```
private Task<Boolean> checkCredTask() {
        Task<Boolean> loginTask = new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() {
            Boolean result = false;
            int flag = verifyCredential();
            if (flag == 1) {
                loadUI();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                result = true;
            } else if (flag == 2) {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
    return loginTask;
    }
```

load UI method

```
ExecutorService execsrv = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
             execsrv.execute(new AdminUI(stage,pane,mb));
             execsrv.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't even compile. `Task<Boolean> loginTask` does not override abstract `call()` method. Even if you wrap

```
ExecutorService execsrv = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
execsrv.execute(new AdminUI(stage,pane,mb));
execsrv.shutdown();
```

in `call()` method it makes no sense, because you are executing new task inside another task.

Assumig that `new AdminUI(stage,pane,mb)` is long running process and return `boolean` you should do it in this way:

```
Task<Boolean> loginTask = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
        // Start the UI 
        AdminUI ui = new AdminUI(stage, pane, mb);
        return ui.getBooleanValue(); 
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

As I said, you are executing `AdminUI` task inside `loginTask` what makes no sense. For now you are waiting only for login task but not for `AdminUI` task. Login task finishes faster than AdminUI that is why indicator stops to early. Extract `AdminUI` to another `Task`. This is pseudo code so you have to do it by your self.

```
Task<Boolean> loginTask= checkCredTask();
loginTask.setOnSucceeded(value -> {
    //****** THIS IS PSEUDO CODE ***********
    //start AdminUITask
    //AdminUITask.setOnSucceeded(value -> {
        //loadBar.hideProgress();
    //});
});
```

Comment: updated the code, and the program works, problem is the indicator stops too early

Comment: It does work, but i when Thread.sleep executes the indicator pauses for 5000ms then continues to rotate. Is there a way to rotate it always

Comment: Where did you add `Thread.sleep(5000)`? Inside loginTask `call()` method? Why do you think that indicator stops to early? Mayby loginTask executes fast enough that you are not able to see indicator.

Comment: I followed your advice, but i think since it involves adding a large amount of nodes to pane freezes the progressindicator. Is there any way to delay the progress. I wrote parts of code inside **runLater()** even so the indicator freezes.